# Iterate over a list that has dynamically called by reflection

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class that contains a couple of lists of different class types which all of them has a `Percent` property; I want to get one of these lists dynamically through it's name (i.e., I want to pass the name of the list to the `GetPropery` method to get the list) and then iterate over the list's entries. The problem is when I use the `GetPropery` method this will get an `object` and does not recognize that it is a List; so I cannot loop over it.
the class that I want to use it's properties:

```
public class ModelOfExcel_VM : Object
{
    public ModelOfExcel_VM()
    {
    }

    public List<Sheet_1_VM> Sheet1 { get; set; }
    public List<Sheet_2_VM> Sheet2 { get; set; }
    public List<Sheet_3_VM> Sheet3 { get; set; }
    public List<Sheet_4_VM> Sheet4 { get; set; }
    public List<Sheet_5_VM> Sheet5 { get; set; }
    public List<Sheet_6_VM> Sheet6 { get; set; }
    public List<Sheet_7_VM> Sheet7 { get; set; }
    public List<Sheet_8_VM> Sheet8 { get; set; }
    public List<Sheet_9_VM> Sheet9 { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the sample code:

```
private void PercentValidation()
{
    ModelOfExcel_VM excel = new ModelOfExcel_VM;
    var pageswithpercent = new List<string>() { "3", "5", "7", "8", "9"}; 

    foreach (var page in pageswithpercent)
    {
        var thisPage = excel.GetType().GetProperty("Sheet" + page).GetValue(excel, null);

        //this loop will lead to an error due thisPage has type of object and is not iteratable.
        foreach (var item in thisPage)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Percent);
        }

    }
}
```

I also have used interfaces but it does not work either because when I use the Type of interface instead of the class Type in the foreach loop I can not use the `Percent` property because it refers to Percent property in `IPercent` interface rather than Percent property in the original class of the object(each list has a different class type but also has implemented the `IPercent` interface). If I use `var`it will refer to `object` type and then as you know I cannot access properties in the class.

the interface approach:

```
interface IPercent
{
    float Percent{ get; set; }
}

private void PercentValidation()
{
    ModelOfExcel_VM excel =  new ModelOfExcel_VM;
    var pageswithpercent = new List<string>() { "3", "5", "7", "8", "9"}; 

    foreach (var page in pageswithpercent)
    {
        var thisPageObject = excel.GetType().GetProperty("Sheet" + page).GetValue(excel, null);

        var thisPage = (IEnumerable<IPercent>)thisPageObject;

        //bellow if I use var instead of IPercent as the type of item it would be recognized as object.
        foreach (IPercent item in thisPage)
        {
            //here the percent property refers to interface itself
            Console.WriteLine(item.Percent);
        }
    }
}
```

it is straightforward in java script but How can I do this in c#?

Comment: "*here the percent property refers to interface itself*" -- that makes no sense. What does `Console.WriteLine` actually print in that case?

Comment: I mean that the percent property does not refer to actual property in the class of the `item` instead it refers to percent property in IPercent interface; so actually it does not print anything, It returns this error: the percent property is inaccessible due its protection level.

Comment: The `IPercent` interface does not have its own `Percent` property as such -- there's no storage for a property in an interface, and therefore no value to print. It just says that things which implement that interface *must* implement that property. You must be confused, but I'm not sure how you came to the conclusion you did

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some things about your question which don't make sense:

1. Your properties are called `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, etc, but you're trying to access properties called `Sheet_1_VM`, `Sheet_2_VM`, etc, using reflection
2. You say you can cast `thisPageObject` to `List<IPercent>`, but this is not possible
3. You say "*here the percent property refers to interface itself*", but this is not possible. `item.Percent` has type `float`, and cannot refer to an interface

However, we can gloss over these issues, and skip to the core question: given an object which might be a `List<Sheet_1_VM>` or a `List<Sheet_2_VM>`, where both `Sheet_1_VM` and `Sheet_2_VM` implement `IPercent`, how can we iterate over each element in the list.

The reason you can't cast a `List<Sheet_1_VM>` to a `List<IPercent>` is because `List<T>` is not covariant. A `List<Sheet_1_VM>` is a list which contains *only* `Sheet_1_VM` objects (or their subclasses): you wouldn't be able to put a `Sheet_2_VM` into a `List<Sheet_1_VM>`. However, if you pretended that your `List<Sheet_1_VM>` was a `List<IPercent>`, then you would be able to put *any* object which implemented `IPercent` into it (by calling `List<T>.Add`). That means you would be able to put a `Sheet_2_VM` into your `List<Sheet_1_VM>`, which obviously makes no sense!

However, `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, and `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant. This means that it only lets you take items *out* of the collection, and doesn't let you put them in (there's no `Add` method). Therefore it is safe to treat a `List<Sheet_1_VM>` as an `IEnumerable<IPercent>`, because there's no danger of anyone putting a `Sheet_2_VM` in.

This lets us write this:

```
public interface IPercent
{
    float Percent { get; }
}

public class Sheet_1_VM : IPercent
{
    public float Percent { get; set; }
}

public class Sheet_2_VM : IPercent
{
    public float Percent { get; set; }
}

public class ModelOfExcel_VM : Object
{
    public List<Sheet_1_VM> Sheet1 { get; set; }
    public List<Sheet_2_VM> Sheet2 { get; set; }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var model = new ModelOfExcel_VM()
        {
            Sheet1 = new List<Sheet_1_VM>()
            {
                new Sheet_1_VM() { Percent = 1.0f },
                new Sheet_1_VM() { Percent = 2.0f },
            },
            Sheet2 = new List<Sheet_2_VM>()
            {
                new Sheet_2_VM() { Percent = 3.0f },
                new Sheet_2_VM() { Percent = 4.0f },
            },
        };

        var pageswithpercent = new List<string>() { "1", "2" }; 

        foreach (var page in pageswithpercent)
        {
            var thisPage = (IEnumerable<IPercent>)model.GetType().GetProperty("Sheet" + page).GetValue(model);

            foreach (var item in thisPage)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Percent);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are completely right, I have made obvious mistakes! I have corrected my question. Thanks for the correction suggestions and comprehending what was in my mind.